Relation Between Perron-Frobenius Theorem and the Left Singular Vector of a Semi-Positive Matrix
I am trying to understand the connection between the Perron-Frobenius theorem and the left singular vector of a semi-positive matrix. Specifically:
The Perron-Frobenius theorem states that for a semi-positive square matrix, there exists a strictly positive eigenvector corresponding to the dominant eigenvalue.
On the other hand, the left singular vector of the matrix, as obtained from the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD), also seems to be strictly positive under similar conditions.
Is it correct to claim that the strictly positive eigenvector guaranteed by the Perron-Frobenius theorem corresponds to the left singular vector in the SVD of the matrix? If so, under what assumptions does this correspondence hold, and how can it be proved?
Thank you for your insights!

What is a semi-positive matrix?

Note that if $M$ has non-negative entries, then the same is true for $MM^T$. Applying the Frobenius theorem to $MM^T$ gives you your result.
